# Upload Image to rest API by form-data

Tags: flutter, http, multipartform-data, form-data

I am trying to send image file to server via rest API in the form of form-data.

```
Future<StreamedResponse> setBusinessLogo(BusinessImage businessLogo) async {
    try {
      var request = MultipartRequest(
          'POST', Uri.parse('$baseUrl/api/BusinessUnits/BusinessLogo'));

      String t = await _getToken();
      request.headers.addAll({
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $t'
      });

      request.fields['BranchId'] = businessLogo.branchId.toString();
      request.fields['ImagePath'] = businessLogo.imagePath.toString();
      request.files.add(MultipartFile.fromBytes(
          'Image', businessLogo.image.readAsBytesSync(),
          filename: t + DateTime.now().toString()));

      return await request.send();
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

But I am getting the error code 400 (Bad Request).

P.S. I have successfully uploaded images using the same code but suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: Issue may be related to backend

Comment: Issue resolved using MultipartFile.fromPath()

Comment: Secondly the filename in above code is pretty large which resulted in bulky payload due to which the error was occuring.